a question about series of function terms
For
$$
S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos (nx)}{n}
$$
its partial   sum  is
$$
S_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\cos (kx)}{k}
$$
Prove:
$$
\liminf_{n}(\min_{0\leq x \leq \pi}(S_n(x)))=-\ln2
$$
I have obtained $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos (nx)}{n}=-\ln2-\ln|\sin \frac{x}{2}|$ and it converges uniformly on any compact set in(0,$2\pi$). I find that  $\min_{0< x < \pi}(S(x))=-\ln 2$. So I guess that $\liminf_{n}(\min_{0\leq x \leq \pi}(S_n(x)))=\min_{0< x < \pi}(S(x))$. It is hard for me to prove it strictly. Can someone help me rigorously prove this?

Hi! Unfortunately it seems you have stumbled on the wrong forum for this question, as MathOverflow is intended for questions arising in original mathematical research (roughly: PhD level and above). Were you perhaps looking for the other Stack Exchange site for maths questions? Best of luck with your studies! ^_^

I am sorry.I will definitely not do this next time. Thank you for reminding me！

Not a problem! I can migrate this question if you haven't already asked it over there
